# How to create layout folder only for phones

Tags: android

I need to be able to use a layout thats in a 'layout' directory for an activity which is in landscape. For phones the view looks like this

Portrait Mode

[image: Portrait]

Landscape Mode

[image]

Tablet Landscape mode[image]

As you can see the landscape tablet layout inherits the views from the layout-land directory. I would like to use the portrait layout in the regular layout directory when the tablet is in landscape mode. Is there any way to accomplish this without having to copy and paste and maintain separate identical files? Is there someway I can put a qualifier on the folder that only makes the layouts for phones?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a layout only for phones then you have to put them in a folder named:

```
 /layout-normal
```

inside of your /res folder.

BTW: you can combine qualifiers, for example you can use:

```
 /layout-normal-port
```

for portrait layouts for "normal" phones etc. just be careful to add the qualifiers in the right order. They must be listed like in Table 2 here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: That doesnt work because the /layout-normal-land directory would be used for all devices.

Comment: and what if you use /layout-normal-port for phones portrait layout and /layout-large-port for tablet portrait layout?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution... So I have to maintain two identical versions of the layout files.. If you find a solution I would greatly appreciate an answer :)